# Make a Http-Request to an specific URL on windows phone

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8, editor, webrequest

My problem is that i have to make a Http-Request to an specific URL. with the parameters: login and password. and the action is Login. Also I have to save the hash and use it for the next requests.
Till now I have this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using PhoneApp1.Resources;

namespace PhoneApp1
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Sample code to localize the ApplicationBar
            //BuildLocalizedApplicationBar();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      const string login = @"sknake";
      const string password = @"";
      const string md5 = @"";

      CookieContainer cookieMonster = new CookieContainer();
      string postArgs = string.Format(
        @"raw_login_password={0}&do=login&url=%2Fforum%2Fusercp.php&vb_login_md5password={2}&vb_login_md5password_utf={2}&s=&securitytoken=guest&vb_login_username={1}&vb_login_password=",
        password,
        login,
        md5
         );

      HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.thinkdigit.com/forum/login.php?do=login");
      req.Method = "POST";
      req.CookieContainer = cookieMonster;
      req.Referer = @"http://www.thinkdigit.com/forum/usercp.php";
      req.ContentType = @"application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
      byte[] buffer = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postArgs);
      req.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
      req.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
      using (Stream reqStream = req.GetRequestStream())
      {
        reqStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        reqStream.Close();
      }
      HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
      using (Stream respStream = response.GetResponseStream())
      {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(respStream))
        {
          string s = sr.ReadToEnd();
          System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: I don't really understand what your problem is. Could you add more detail to your question? Is it not working? If not, what error are you getting? Or are you looking for a code review?

Comment: what is going wrong exactly?

Comment: It says if I go to debug it wont run

Comment: Can you show the exact error message?